# What is shortcut to navigate to file in project structure

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I used to ctrl+lbm click on package name in file declaration

```
package ua.sharehelp.volnteerereceive.ui.fragments.request_create
import ...
class RequestCreateFragment{}
```

and it navigates to file in project structure
[image]

however same hotkey can open unit test files instead. Through it looks pretty random what will be opened.
How to navigate only to working directories?

Comment: I assume you might have the same package/class in both sources and test roots. When the open file in editor is highlighted in green a test root will be used. Otherwise you'll see a source one. E.g. https://prnt.sc/n8f6a5babCMU Does it looks like your case?

Comment: You can also try using Shift+Shift shortcut for searching the needed class.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov yes, whoever i want to open source package even if test exists. About shif tsearch - sure I can do it. but I am actually interested in  other classes in package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found shortcut Alt+F1 ->1 . opens currently selected file in Project view